# Azure Logic Apps - FTP Trigger

Tags: azure, ftp, sftp, azure-logic-apps

I got a strange problem with Azure Logic Apps.

It's a very simple case, really.

Scenario:

- Logic App reads directory from FTP on 'file created'.
- Logic App reads directory from SFTP on 'file created'.

Nothing else.

SFTP and FTP server are reachable. No Firewalls, no security whatsoever (despite SFTP cert) for testing purposes.

Now there is one Logic App that was created about a year ago. This one is up and running. Almost no errors.

Every other Logic App I'm creating successfully authenticates against the same ftp and sftp respectively. From the same Location. Same Azure Subscription. Everything's the same. No difference except it's another Resource Group.

Even using the exact same ftp connection resource in another Logic App throws 'Bad request'.

On 'file created' trigger the Logic App throws 'Bad Request'. Most times... Say, 9/10 times I get 'Bad request'. 1 time it works.

Does anyone know what's going on here? I'm really struggling to resolve this issue.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it may be network issues. Can you confirm when this kind of problem started?

Comment: No, not really. As I said, the existing Logic App works like a charm. It's every new one I create that doesn't work. Also, on creation you need to authenticate against the FTP/SFTP. Authentication ALWAYS works. Never got a 'Bad Request' there...

Comment: in this case, you can download both arm files and compare with they're using the same version of api connectors

Comment: Good point, didn't try that yet!
I'll have a look and give some feedback!

Comment: Just for info: I did compare both templates and they were identical. I mean, I did create the exact same logic in another resource group, so that's kind of what I expected. But even the API Version was the same. I even exported and imported the functional one but the issue persists. Opened a microsoft ticket now and already got someone contact me. I'll update my post once we know whats up.